# CLion CMake problems

Tags: cmake, clion

I am having a problem when loading CMake on CLion. I'm attempting to setup my proper environment for Arduino programming.

I'm probably missing something obvious, but I was unable to find a functional solution to this. Could anyone give me a hint as to what is causing the following errors?

```
Error:The CMAKE_C_COMPILER:
 avr-gcc 
is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.
Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment 
variable "CC" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_C_COMPILER to the full path to 
the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.

Error:The CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:
  avr-g++
is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.
Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment 
variable "CXX" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to the full path 
to the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.
```

Comment: You don't have a proper C and C++ compiler in your path, at least not one called avr-gcc and avr-g++. Either install them or add the full path in the given variables CMAKE_C_COMPILER and CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER.

Comment: Hmm, I couldn't find anything in MinGW called "avr-gcc" or "avr-g++", only the normal "gcc" and "g++".

Comment: Then set the variables accordingly. Check related questions and the CMake documentation.

Comment: The question is too complex for answering in several words. There is the issue in CLion tracker with several approaches for the [problem solution](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-364).

Answer (score 0):

I got it working following the steps given in the arduino-cmake repo. If you're working on windows make sure you have the arduino sdk installed. And set the correct path in to the sdk.

If you're working on linux make sure you have all the correct dependencies installed as specified in the readme.md in the github repo.

And last but not least, ensure that de cmake directory and toolchain file are present in the project folder.

See
https://github.com/arduino-cmake/arduino-cmake
For proper instructions.